# Guidelines to handle exception in a multithreading

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am developing a WPF application that follows MVVM architecture. This application is multithreaded. Now I would like to know how should I handle exceptions in my application.

Please let me know the guidelines to handle exception in multithreaded WPF application that follows MVVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you search for a specific exception add a break point to your exception line and check call stack

if you want a general catch all exception then perhaps [DispatcherUnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.dispatcherunhandledexception.aspx) in your App.xaml will do the job you want. Check Documentation on this link about other threads handling.

Comment: There are some exceptions for which I need to display message. e.g, Database connection "Open" operation fail. and I would Like to generate the message string from the point of origin of the exception so that the actual reason can be specified.What is the best way to handle exception?? should I handle all exception using  DispatcherUnhandledException or should I handle the exceptions in each of the ViewModel?? I shall be glad if you kindly refer to a application code that is developed using WPF and follows MVVM.